# Problem nuxt.js Vue.js with image slider change of photo first passage the second photo does not display the backslide1 is not added to the dom

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

here my template component

```js
<template>
  <div
    id="backMaPage"
    class="slider backSlideSize mobileBackSlideSize d-flex flex-column justify-content-between align-items-between"
  >
    <div
      class="larg100 textSlide margTitre margTitreMobile d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center"
    >
      <b-icon
        @mouseenter="stopRotation()"
        @mouseleave="startRotation()"
        @click="prev"
        class="bg-white mobileSizeIcon"
        role="button"
        icon="chevron-left"
        animation="fade"
        font-scale="3"
        aria-label="Help"
      ></b-icon>
      <div v-for="number in [currentNumber]" :key="number">
        <h1
          class="rounded-pill backSize mobileBackSize mobileBackSize550 bg-white"
        >
          {{ currentMsg }}
        </h1>
      </div>

      <b-icon
        @mouseenter="stopRotation()"
        @mouseleave="startRotation()"
        @click="next"
        class="bg-white mobileSizeIcon"
        role="button"
        icon="chevron-right"
        animation="fade"
        font-scale="3"
        aria-label="Help"
      ></b-icon>
    </div>
    <div
      class="larg100 mb-3 pl-3 d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center"
    >
      <img
        @mouseenter="afficherMasquer()"
        @mouseleave="afficherMasquer()"
        role="button"
        width="160px"
        height="160px"
        class="mr-3 justify-content-left bordureProfil rounded-circle ombre"
        src="../assets/moi5.jpg"
        alt="photo profil développeur web"
      />
      <div id="dialPhoto" class="supprimDialPhotoMob afficher">
        <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="miniFleche"></div>
          <div
            class="backDial blocapMob blocapMob450 bg-white d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center"
          >
            <h5 class="bg-white blocapFontMob">
              Hello ! Je m'appelle Gérald, je suis Développeur web Fullstack
              Javascript . Bienvenue à vous !
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "maPage",
  data() {
    return {
      messages: [
        "Développeur Web",
        "Spécialisé en javascript",
        "Développeur Frontend Vue.js",
        "Développeur Backend Node.js",
        "Intégrateur Prestashop",
        "Webmaster optimisation Seo",
        "Développeur Fullstack Js"
      ],
      currentNumber: 0,
      timer: null
    };
  },
  created() {},
  mounted: function() {
    this.load();
    this.startRotation();
  },

  methods: {
    afficherMasquer() {
      if (
        document.getElementById("dialPhoto").style.display == "none" ||
        document.getElementById("dialPhoto").style.display == ""
      ) {
        document.getElementById("dialPhoto").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("dialPhoto").style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    load: function() {
      window.onload = function() {
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide");
      };
    },
    startRotation: function() {
      this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 5000);
    },

    stopRotation: function() {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.timer = null;
    },

    next: function() {
      let backMaPage = document.getElementById("backMaPage");
      this.currentNumber += 1;
      console.log(this.currentNumber);

      /*
      if (this.currentNumber == 0) {
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide");
      }
      */

      if (this.currentNumber == 1) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide1");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 2) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide1");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide2");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 3) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide2");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide3");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 4) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide3");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide4");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 5) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide4");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide5");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 6) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide5");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide6");
      }

      if (this.currentNumber > 6) {
        this.currentNumber = 0;
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide6");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide");
      }
    },
    prev: function() {
      let backMaPage = document.getElementById("backMaPage");
      this.currentNumber -= 1;

      if (this.currentNumber == 0) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide1");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide");
      }

      if (this.currentNumber == 1) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide2");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide1");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 2) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide3");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide2");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 3) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide4");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide3");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 4) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide5");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide4");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 5) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide6");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide5");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 6) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide6");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber < 0) {
        this.currentNumber = 6;
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide6");
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    currentMsg: function() {
      return this.messages[Math.abs(this.currentNumber) % this.messages.length];
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.backSlide {
  background-image: url("../assets/roche2.jpg");
  animation: opacBack1 1s ease-in-out;
}
.backSlide1 {
  background-image: url("../assets/js.jpg");
  animation: opacBack2 1s ease-in-out;
}
.backSlide2 {
  background-image: url("../assets/ecole.jpg");
  animation: opacBack3 1s ease-in-out;
}
.backSlide3 {
  background-image: url("../assets/cerveau.jpg");
  animation: opacBack4 1s ease-in-out;
}
.backSlide4 {
  background-image: url("../assets/raw.jpg");
  animation: opacBack5 1s ease-in-out;
}
.backSlide5 {
  background-image: url("../assets/matrice.jpeg");
  animation: opacBack6 1s ease-in-out;
}
.backSlide6 {
  background-image: url("../assets/boreale.jpg");
  animation: opacBack7 1s ease-in-out;
}
.backSize {
  width: 15em;
}
.backDial {
  width: 20em;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.miniFleche {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;

  border-right: 10px solid white;
}
.afficher {
  display: none;
}
.ombre:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #748928ff;
  animation: pulse 1.3s infinite;
}
@keyframes opacBack1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacBack2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacBack3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacBack4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacBack5 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacBack6 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes opacBack7 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  }
}
</style>
```

here image slide photo 1 First passage
[image]

here second picture not played first passage the picture backslide remove but the backslide1 not add on the DOM

[image]

and here in the second passage it's works the picture 2 is played and all works

[image]

My question is what's the solution ? and why is not add for the first passage but after the first passage of the slide the pictures all works .

and this only concerns the second picture in the first pass the other backslides work except the javascript picture for the first passage.

the bug is in the first turn of the slider.
In the second round there is no problem with pictures

Answer (score 0):

the solution is in this code function

```js
next: async function() {
      let backMaPage = document.getElementById("backMaPage");
      this.currentNumber += 1;
      console.log(this.currentNumber);

      /*
      if (this.currentNumber == 0) {
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide");
      }
      */

      if (this.currentNumber == 1) {
        await backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide");
        await backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide1");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 2) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide1");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide2");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 3) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide2");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide3");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 4) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide3");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide4");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 5) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide4");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide5");
      }
      if (this.currentNumber == 6) {
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide5");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide6");
      }

      if (this.currentNumber > 6) {
        this.currentNumber = 0;
        backMaPage.classList.remove("backSlide6");
        backMaPage.classList.add("backSlide");
      }
    },
```

it's works with asynchrone